# Sockets: BufferedReader/InputStream & BufferedWriter/OutputStream won't work

Tags: java, sockets, stream, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

So i'm trying to make a server/client solution using BufferedReader and BufferedWriter, but it won't work! Using only DataInputStream and DataOutputStream worked perfectly fine, but nothing printed out with the Buffered objects. Where is my error?

```
public class TServer {

   static final int PORT = 8001;
   static final int QUEUE = 50;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT, QUEUE)) {
           Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
           BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
           BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));

           System.out.println(input.readLine());
           output.write("this is the server!");
           output.flush();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           System.out.println(e.getMessage());
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
}


public class TClient {

   static final String HOST = "localhost";
   static final int PORT = 8001;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       try (Socket socket = new Socket(HOST, PORT)) {
           BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
           BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));

           output.write("this is the client");
           output.flush();
           System.out.println(input.readLine());
       } catch (IOException e) {
           System.out.println(e.getMessage());
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/io/ServerSocketEx.java#l165 might be helpful to you

Answer (score 1):

> Using only DataInputStream and DataOutputStream worked perfectly fine, but nothing printed out with the Buffered objects.

The Client is sending the following:

```
output.write("this is the client");
```

The Server is trying to read a line with the BufferedReader:

```
System.out.println(input.readLine());
```

But no line will be received as the end of line terminator is not sent (hence, the method will block (same goes for the Server, which does not send the end of line terminator)). See the API for [BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29), which states:

> Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `readLine` method of BufferedReader, so you should write newline-terminated string in corresponding BufferedWriter. Like:

```
    output.write("this is the client");
    output.newLine();
```